# How to access data from custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch

Preface: I'm fairly new to React (Coming over from Angular). I know things a similar but different.
I have referenced the following SO threads to no avail in my situation:
[React not displaying data after successful fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224628/react-not-displaying-data-after-successful-fetch)

[Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c)

Currently, I'm trying to get my data to display from an API I developed. I'm used to the Angular approach which would call for a `ngFor` in the template for most data showcase situations.

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around what I have to do here in order to display my data. The data is expected to be an array of objects which I would then parse to display.

I also receive the following error:  `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {data}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I've searched high and low for a solution but sadly, nothing I've seen has worked for me. (All of the answers on SO are using the class-based version of React, of which I am not).

You can see my data output in the following screenshot:

[image: Drone Data From API]

I am also including my custom hook code and the component that is supposed to render the data:

CUSTOM DATA FETCH HOOK

```
interface Drone{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    model: string;
    price: number;
}

export function useGetData(urlpath:string) {
    const [droneData, setData] = useState<any>()

    
    async function handleDataFetch(path:string){
        const result = await fetch(`https://drone-collections-api-jc.herokuapp.com${path}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'x-access-token': 'Bearer API-TOKEN'
            }
        })

        const response = await result.json();
        setData(response)
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        handleDataFetch(urlpath)
    })

    return droneData
}
```

THE DRONE COMPONENT

```
import { useGetData } from '../../custom-hooks'


export const Drones = () => {

    let data = useGetData('/drones')
    console.log(data)

    

    // const DisplayDrone = ( ) => {
    //     return (
    //         Array.prototype.map( data => {
    //         <div>{ data.name }</div>
    //         })
    //     )
    // }
    


    return ( 
        <div>
            <h1>Hello Drones</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, for more context, the current code can be found at this repo: https://github.com/carter3689/testing-drone-frontend

Please, help me understand what I'm missing. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several locations that needed to be fixed

In `fetchData.tsx`

```
export function useGetData(urlpath: string) {
  const [droneData, setData] = useState<any>([]);

  async function handleDataFetch(path: string) {
    const result = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
      ...
    });
    const response = await result.json();
    setData(response);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDataFetch(urlpath);
  }, []);
```

Explanation:

1. you need a "blank" array for looping through. I guess that the error causes by the fact that at the start, before the data is fetched, there is nothing to loop through. It's same as doing `undefined.map()`, which is obviously fail.
2. You need a dependencies array for `useEffect`. Right now your code will do an infinite loop since everytime it get data, it update the state, thus re-run the `useEffect` and repeat. Add dependencies array limit when that `useEffect` will run

In `Drones.tsx`

```
return (
  <div>
    {data.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>}
  </div>
)
```

Not much to say here. I don't use Angular so I'm not sure why you use `Array.prototype.map`, but in React you can loop through your variable directly. I also have a [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-violet-tjwoo?file=/src/components/Drones/Drones.tsx) for your project (I use public API)